# Postgres multiple columns in WHERE col1, col2 IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can easily do:

`select * from cities where name in ('Paris', 'London');`

but can I also select the rows with combination of columns?

`select * from cities where city, country in (('Paris', 'France'), ('London', 'UK'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use parentheses:

```
select * from cities where (city, country) in (('Paris', 'France'), ('London', 'UK'))
```

The syntax is that of “Composite Values”. See the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/rowtypes.html):

> The external text representation of a composite value consists of items that are interpreted according to the I/O conversion rules for the individual field types, plus decoration that indicates the composite structure. The decoration consists of parentheses (( and )) around the whole value, plus commas (,) between adjacent items.